# How op amp works?

Tags: operational-amplifier

If I ground the V- input from a 741 op amp, I still need a trimpot connected with the offset null terminals as pictured below to regulate the output?

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [learningaboutelectronics.com](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/images/Offset-null-connection-op-amp.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That basically won't work. With no feedback, the output will be wildly noisy and drifty, and you won't be able to get a stable output. The output will basically be the open loop gain (typically about 200,000) times both the input offset and noise. An LM741, for instance, has a typical thermal drift of 15 uV/deg C, which will produce an output drift of 3 volts per degree C.

Answer (score 0):

The offset trim pot is optional - if you don't care about the offset, you don't need to include the pot.

Answer (score -1):

With this config, you can adjust the offset so that the output is mid rail.

Comment: In theory yes, in practice no because there is no feedback so the gain is very high. Noise, temperature and drift will make sure the output does not stay at midpoint whatever you do. Feedback is needed for this.